# Qual é a finalidade do "X" no início de alguns nomes de headers?

Tags: http, http-headers

Existem headers específicos em HTTP que tem a finalidade de passar alguma informação. Como por exemplo o `Content-Type` que informa o mime do conteúdo que se quer receber ou enviar. Também temos o `Content-Length` que determina o tamanho em bytes de uma resposta.

Porém tenho percebido alguns headers, que possuem algumas características comuns, como por exemplo: `X-Csrf-Token`, `X-Frame-Options`, `X-XSS-Protection` ou `X-UA-Compatible`.

Todos eles tem a finalidade de informar algo, obviamente, como todos os outros.

Porém eu estou curioso para saber por que todos eles precisam começar com a letra "X".

- Tem algum significado quando o header começa com "X"? E se tem, qual é?
- Seria para criar algo customizado? Por exemplo: Se eu quisesse inventar um header para informar a versão da aplicação, eu poderia criar algo como `X-App-Version`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561381/custom-http-headers-naming-conventions

Answer (score 7):

A utilização do "X" é uma convenção dos desenvolvedores de protocolos customizados.

(Prática já desencorajada pela [RFC 6648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6648))

Nunca encontrei uma versão oficial da utilização do "X", mas a versão mais difundida é que é um X de extra, um "extra header".

Estes Header são exatamente para enviar alguma informação customizada no Header, como por exemplo, um Token de acesso.